# how to prevent h2o.init() creating libxgboost4j_gpu*.so files in temp directory

Tags: r, h2o, temp

when running h2o.init() (using the latest package version) from r, it is creating libxgboost4j_gpu*.so files within temp directory which take significant amount of space and pile up (when run several times). Does anyone know how to stop this?